# How exactly does a control moment gyroscope work?

Tags: rotational-dynamics, rigid-body-dynamics, gyroscopes, space-travel

I've searched a lot, but have not been able to find a proper explanation for the working of a [control moment gyroscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_moment_gyroscope). Could someone please explain it to me, preferably with vectors?

Comment: In its current form your question isn't specific enough. It could be that you are asking: "I understand gyroscopic precession, but I am looking to understand how a control moment gyroscope is *implemented*. It could be that you are asking: "I am looking to understand gyroscopic precession." Well, chances are you are asking the second question. (Gyroscopic precession is a question that is being asked about over and over and over again.) But preferably you should make your question specific.

Comment: Well, I think that is my bad. To be clear, I understand gyroscopic precession, but don't understand how is implemented in a CMG. Thanks again :)

Comment: Here's the thing. If you have learned about gyroscopic precession from a source that presents it properly then how to implement a control moment gyroscope is immediately obvious. Let me take the simpler example of using control moment gyroscopes to suppress roll of a ship. The CMG is effective to suppress roll induced by waves (no saturation of the CMG unit), but if you would attempt to counteract *list* then the CMG unit will quickly become saturated. Proper understanding of gyroscopic behavior makes that distinction immediately obvious.